# Default projects in android studio come with errors

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I constantly get the following error:
Unable to serialize DslActivationStatus state. 
I have searched the solutions but they dont work, its from the default project that you can create from android studio.

Comment: Sounds like a runtime error, is that right? If so, post the full stack trace.

Comment: @Michael It is not a runtime error, its during the project initial creation. I dont even have time to build it. Would you like the trace of the creation?

Answer (score 0):

You may have some missing package of android studio while installation of android studio

You may reinstall the android studio and while reinstalling you have to connect continues to internet without intrupt of internet connection.

Cause some missing package have very difficult to find.

Hope you get help!

Comment: Tried it doesnt work, same issue as before. I have AMD processor on my laptop but I have installed all the prequisites.